# How do i target an unspecified file that recently got used

Tags: batch-file

Im making a sort-of anti-virus but i still have 1 problem.

```
findstr /i "hack" *.*
(target *.* as a specified file)
```

or with for?

```
for /f
```

So i find a file that contains the word "hack" in it but how do i target that one file now?
Or is there maybe a way around that with the "for" command? I would try to use "for" but im dont actualy know how to.
So i tried to use %%n but that didnt help. Does anyone recommend "for" with a solution or should i stick to findstr?

Edit*

This solved my problem

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /i /m "hack" *.*) do echo "%%a"
```

Comment: Run `FINDSTR` with the `/M` option as a command with `FOR /F`.

Comment: could you show me the full command? Im still not fully sure how to use for though. `for /f in ('findstr /i /m "hack" *.*) do (...)`

Comment: `for /f "delims=" %%a  in ('findstr /i /m "hack" *.*) do echo "%%a"`

Comment: Thanks so much! This solved it!

Comment: Instead of including the solution into your question, I recommend that you post it as an answer, so the question appears solved; note that you can even [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) your own answer then...